# How do I disable the byetcode requirement for scanning Java projects in sonarqube 6.5.0.27846?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a java codebase I need to scan in sonarqube, but when I run the scanner I get:

```
Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
```

I don't have the classes; the code I was given wasn't compiled. It's also a pretty complex application and I don't really have time to figure out how to build it myself. Is there a way I can force the analysis to run without any binaries available?

Thanks for any help/ideas!

-Jason

(Also, I ran sonarqube 5.x last year on java code, and definitely did not have to use classfiles for that analysis. I figured this was a new "feature" for version 6, but the documentation says this has been since version 4.12 (?!)

Comment: Just to precise one thing : in your last sentence 4.12 is the version of SonarJava (the java analyzer) not SonarQube.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out after I posted. I wound up downgrading the sonarjava plugin to 4.11 and using that in place of the one that came with my sonarqube installation. It worked and I was able to run my analysis without the warning about the bytecode files. Thanks for pointing this out though.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass any valid directory as the value of `sonar.java.binaries`, for example:

```
mkdir /tmp/empty
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.java.binaries=/tmp/empty
```

This will bypass the problem raised by the Java analyzer,
but keep in mind that the analysis results won't be perfectly accurate.
It's very common to have some false positives when the analyzer doesn't have access to the bytecode binaries.

Comment: This wasn't how I fixed my problem (see my comment above) but this is a good idea.